# Internal navigation rejected - <allow-navigation> not set for url='mycustomprotocol://localhost'

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am implementing a cordova application for iOS with a custom protocol.

The custom protocol is set with the use of the plugin cordova-plugin-ionic-webview via `<preference name="iosScheme" value="mycustomprotocol" />` in the config.xml.

I am getting the following error in Xcode

```
ERROR Internal navigation rejected - <allow-navigation> not set for url='mycustomprotocol://localhost'
```

The [plugin docs of cordova-plugin-ionic-webview](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview#iosscheme) describe the use of the allow navigation like as follows

```
<allow-navigation href="mycustomprotocol://*"/>
```

I tried the following allow-navigation values, but none of them seems to work and the error remained.

```
<allow-navigation href="mycustomprotocol:*" />
<allow-navigation href="mycustomprotocol://*" />
<allow-navigation href="mycustomprotocol://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="mycustomprotocol://localhost" />
```

I also tried the wildcard `<allow-navigation href="*" />` but this does not work for custom protocols as stated in the [cordova-plugin-whitelist documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by using `<allow-navigation href="*://*" />`

Comment: Yeah only this works but why is it such a mess? I tried all the other options too and naturally don't like to asterisk everything */sigh/*